# Lua arguments at wrong memory location

Tags: c++, exception, lua, lua-api

When parsing variables from lua, lua is acting strangely.

C++:

```
int LuaManager::SetTimer(lua_State *pLua)
{
    if (!lua_isstring(pLua, 0)) throw "expected: string";
    if (!lua_isnumber(pLua, 1)) throw "expected: number";

    std::string callback = lua_tostring(pLua, 0);
    double delay = lua_tonumber(pLua, 1);
    Timer timer = Timer(callback, delay);

    return 0;
}
```

lua:

```
SetTimer("Durp", 10);
```

I get a "First-chance exception at 0x76C44598: Microsoft C++ exception: char at memory location 0x00D7F588" from the line

```
std::string callback = lua_tostring(pLua, 0);
```

When I debug the code and press continue when the exception pops up it throws random variables into the variable. The same goes for the `double delay`.

However when I say:

```
std::string callback = lua_tostring(pLua, -2);
double delay = lua_tonumber(pLua, -1);
```

It will still give the exception but the correct variables are thrown in.

Comment: If an exception is thrown the variable is most certainly not going to contain a valid value.

Comment: 0 is never a valid stack slot. The first stack slot is 1.

Comment: Oh you're completely right such a stupid oversight of mine.
Any idea though on why -1 and -2 were also returning the correct values?

Comment: Negative indices count from the top down the stack.

Comment: I wonder if compiling lua with `LUA_USE_APICHECK` would have caught this.

Answer (score 1):

From my memories, the line

```
std::string callback = lua_tostring(pLua, 0);
```

should be

```
std::string callback = lua_tostring(pLua, 1);
```

because indexes in lua start at 1.